# Fastendpoints return 404

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, fast-endpoints

I'm using Fastendpoints for my .NET8 project. I'm having an issue with `change-password` endpoint.

```
public class ChangePasswordEndpoint : Endpoint<ChangePasswordRequest>
{
    private readonly IAuthService _authService;

    public ChangePasswordEndpoint(IAuthService authService) => _authService = authService;

    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("/auth/change-password");
        Claims("UserId");
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(ChangePasswordRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirstValue("UserId");
        req.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(userId);
        await _authService.ChangePasswordAsync(req);
        await SendOkAsync(ct);
    }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services
    .AddFastEndpoints()
    .AddJWTBearerAuth(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GeneralSettings:JwtSecret").Value)
    .AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.SwaggerDocument();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value), ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.RegisterServices();
builder.Services.ConfigureEmailSender(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.ConfigureAppSettings(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication()
   .UseAuthorization()
   .UseFastEndpoints(c =>
{
    c.Endpoints.RoutePrefix = "api";
    c.Serializer.Options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase; 
});
app.UseSwaggerGen();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.ApplyPendingMigrations();

app.Run();
```

When I test this endpoint without Authorization header stated I always receive 404 as a response. The expected behavior would be to receive 401 if JWT is not entered. Other routes that are stated as anonymous work fine. Having this in mind, I'm guessing that I misconfiguration issue but I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: Error 404 is NOT FOUND.  So either the URL is not found or you do not have permission to access the URL.  Error 401 indicates you found the URL but do not have permission to access the Route.  So you have something like MyURL.com/MyRoute

Comment: @jdweng actually the 404 is caused by asp.net's cookie middleware redirecting unauthenticated requests to a login page, which is the default behavior (which is overridable). see my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

for anybody else coming across this, the underlying cause is when multiple auth schemes are being used (jwt bearer & cookies) as done here due to the call to `.AddIdentity<>()`, cookie auth scheme becomes the default as it's registered last.

the solution is to explicitly specify that the "change password" endpoint should only be authenticated via the jwt scheme like so:

```cs
public override void Configure()
{
    Post("/auth/change-password");
    AuthSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

more info can be found in [this github issue](https://github.com/FastEndpoints/FastEndpoints/issues/583#issuecomment-1912116003).